# R: How do you pass the value of an expression to a function that rejects an expression argument?

Tags: r, function, types, attributes, evaluation

MY code, below, now fixed, suffered from a different defect than I thought, unrelated to my title question. The real problem, and its solution, was supplied by @Roland, below.

I have a pair of functions, shown below, which together are supposed to return a list of the values of the column attribute named in attrC. When run, R objects that " Error in attr(x, which = get("attrC"), exact = TRUE): 'which' must be of mode character".

I have tried replacing attrC with get("attrC") and eval(attrC). Neither works.

I have three closely related questions. A good answer would answer all three.

1. How do I make this particular function work?
2. How can I tell, from the form of an R function or its documentation, when an argument which is required to be of a given type will accept a variable or expression that evaluates to that type?
3. If the answer to (1.) has not already supplied it: Is there a generic way to provide a function that requires an argument of given type and does not accept a name or expression which evaluates to that type, with the value from such a name or expression.

.

```
    ColAttr <- function(x, attrC, ifIsNull) {
# Returns column attribute named in attrC, if present, else isNullC.
  atr <- attr(x, attrC, exact = TRUE)
  atr <- if (is.null(atr)) {ifIsNull} else {atr}
  atr
}

AtribLst <- function(df, attrC, isNullC){
# Returns list of values of the col attribute attrC, if present, else isNullC
  lapply(df, ColAttr, attrC=attrC, ifIsNull=isNullC)
}

stub93 <- AtribLst(cps_00093.df, attrC="label", isNullC=NA)
```

Comment: (if my edit doesn't show, just add a period as its own paragraph, on an empty line, after your numbered list ... SO-markdown doesn't transition well between lists and code blocks.)

Comment: Can you generate a reproducible example? And I think the attrC default value should not same with variable name, it is really confusing. It also may cause you problem.

Comment: Dear @dracodoc -- After messing around with them a bit more, I am increasingly confused about what my functions are actually doing. Let me say what I thought I was doing. I thought I was passing the variable attrC with the value "label" into the execution environment of AtribList. Then inside AtribList, lapply calls colAttr, which I wanted to find attrC and then hand "label" to the which argument of attr. That is not happening. Is the problem that ColAttr is defined in the Global environment rather than inside of AtribLst?

Comment: Your lapply call is wrong. Instead of x = df it should be attrC = attrC, isNullC = NA. You want to loop over the columns and not use the whole df in each iteration.

Comment: Dear @Roland -- You are absolutely correct. And that is the real answer to my question, because the code was not failing where I thought it was. Kudos and thanks. I'll accept this as an answer, if you like, and then edit my question so that the answer makes sense.